# why array is not obsolete after collection comes in java

Tags: java

In java post collection , we can do all thing which we could do by array and some other stuffs using collection . so my question is can array be obsolete in future ?

Comment: Any answer as to whether or not arrays might be removed from Java would be pure speculation at best

Comment: This is not an answerable question. We cannot know the future. We can only speculate, and a request for speculation is not considered a proper question on StackOverflow. Arrays are unlikely to go away because they are actually used inside the collection classes, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: No, it won' t be obsolete. They are widely used through Java.

Comment: For normal usage, it already basically is obsolete; there's almost never a good reason to use object arrays anymore unless you're implementing a collection -- in which case you need to use low level arrays to implement them.  What else do you want?

Comment: How exactly are you going to *implement* a collection, then?

Answer (score 2):

Example: Load an image into some kind of graphics buffer. The graphics buffer is most likely a 2-dimensional array which will be written 50 times per second. With tens of millions of elements you most probably wouldn't want to change this to a List of Lists. ;)